# Concatenate letter to a string with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x, concatenation

I wanted to create a for-loop which will check the items on a list, and if condition is met, 
a letter will be added every time to a string.

This is what I made:

```
words = 'bla bla 123 554 gla gla 151 gla 10'

def checkio(words):
for i in words.split():
    count = ''
    if isinstance(i, str) == True:
        count += "k"
    else:
        count += "o"
```

My supposed to be count result is 'kkookkoko' (5 times cause of 5 strings).

what I get from this function is that count = 'k'.

why does the letters do not concatenate through my for loop?

Please help!

Regards..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are setting `count` to `''` on each iteration, that line should be outside:

```
count = ''
for ...:
```

Also, you can just do

```
if isinstance(i, str):
```

it's not necessary to compare with `== True`, because `isinstance` returns a *boolean*.

With your code you will always get a string full of `k`. **Why?** Because `words.split()` will return a list of strings, therefore, the `if` will always be `True`.

**How can you solve it?** You can use a `try-except` block:

```
def checkio(words):
    count = ''
    for i in words.split():
        try: # try to convert the word to an integer
            int(i) 
            count += "o"
        except ValueError as e: # if the word cannot be converted to an integer
            count += "k"
    print count
```

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting `count` to be the empty string at each start of the loop. Put `count=''` before the `for` loop.
Other problems with your code: there's no return value for your function, the code lacks indentation, the `== True` part is obsolete. Also `words.split()` will only work if `words` is a string - and in that case,  `isinstance(i, str)` will always be true.